# Symfony: should I add the rabbitmq:consumer command to crontab?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I have read many (great) articles on RabbitMQ integration into a Symfony application.

The [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle) makes it very easy to ingrate it, and it provides the convenient `rabbitmq:consumer` command to consume messages from a queue like this:

```
app/console rabbitmq:consumer -m 50 upload_picture
```

I have a question however. Should you recommend to add this command to crontab? Are there any best practices about it?

Comment: A side note -m 50 is not reliable all the time. For example, if you have a few methods coming to queue from time to time you'll have problems with lost connections. It happens because of a long idle period. Better to limit the actual time the command works. All connection timeout could be bound to this limit. Consumer works for 1 hour and exits so the timeout could be set to 1 hour 20 minutes. This is something rabbitmq bundle misses but it is available in enqueue bundle (--limit-time="now + 1 hour" option).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The more accepted method is to keep your consumer running. There are tools like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) and [Circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that can help you with that. See [this discussion](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle/issues/277). But if you can get your consumer to exit when there are no more messages, you could also use cron. Although this might cause a delay in consuming the messages. You can't react on messages instantly. Users might have to wait a minute before any task is started / mail is received.

Please take the following into account when running your consumer (or any PHP code for that matter) for a long time:

Try to avoid memory usage accumulation. Don't keep appending to arrays without ever clearing them. This means for instance that you shouldn't use *FingersCrossedHandler* in Monolog since this keeps a buffer of log messages. Fine for a single request, not for a daysworth of debug messages.

Even when you are careful, PHP might leak memory. What can you say, PHP... (That could indeed be a catchphrase) In my situation I have a cronjob installed that restarts the workers every night, but in theory the consumers could run about a month before they run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for as it was never mentioned in the RabbitMQ for Symfony tutorials. It seems there is an interesting Symfony bundle to handle automatic Supervisord configuration for the RabbitMQBundle: https://github.com/Phobetor/rabbitmq-supervisor-bundle

Comment: The issue link under "this discussion" is off.

Comment: I would avoid the bundle mentionned in first comment it got real reliability issues.

Comment: @TomToms Yep I agree. It was overkill and I ended up doing my own supervisor config, which is quite simple. I configured my PHP Docker container to automatically install and launch supervisor and it works really fine.